# how to fill color under intersection and curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

My MWE is as follows:

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,tikz-3dplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles,intersections,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,math,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc,positioning,hobby,bending,shadings,fit,arrows,shapes.arrows,fadings,patterns,patterns.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar,colorbrewer,fillbetween,groupplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    f(\x)=pow(\x,2)+2;
    g(\x)=pow(\x,4)-2*pow(\x,2)+1;
  }]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines*=middle, axis line style={-stealth'}, major tick length=2pt,
  every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=west,}, xlabel=$x$,
  every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south,}, ylabel={$y$},
  enlargelimits=upper, % ticks=none,
  ymin=-0.5, xmin=-2.3,
  ]

  \addplot[red,smooth,domain=-2:2,line width=1,name path=curve_f] {f(\x)};
  \addplot[blue,smooth,domain=-1.85:1.85,line width=1,name path=curve_g] {g(\x)};

  \path[domain=-1.85:0,name path=f(x)_1] plot (\x,{f(\x)});
  \path[domain=-2:0,name path=g(x)_1] plot (\x,{g(\x)});
  \path[name intersections={of=f(x)_1 and g(x)_1,by=A}];
  \node[circle,fill=green,minimum size=6pt,inner sep=0pt] at (A){};

  \draw[gray,dashed] (A) -- ($(0,0)!(A)!(1,0)$);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to fill color under intersection A marked in green and along the curve marked in blue, like shown in following figure:

[image]

Comment: your code is not a MWE!

Comment: Richt: it fails the test of copy&compile.

Comment: Please make it easier for others to help you. We just want to copy your code and compile it, without guessing what packages/libraries/etc. you are using. A ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: @SandyG thanks for your comment, just now I modified it.

Comment: Looks like you forgot `\documentclass`.

Comment: @SandyG yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that you only load those libraries and packages you really need: `pgfplots` already loads `tikz`, you don't use `tikz-3dplot` as well as most of the libraries you load.

The following is more or less taken from the [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    f(\x)=pow(\x,2)+2;
    g(\x)=pow(\x,4)-2*pow(\x,2)+1;
  }]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines*=middle, axis line style={-stealth'}, major tick length=2pt,
  every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=west}, 
  xlabel=$x$,
  every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=south}, 
  ylabel={$y$},
  enlargelimits=upper, % ticks=none,
  ymin=-0.5, xmin=-2.3,
  ]

  \addplot[red, smooth, domain=-2:2, line width=1, name path=curve_f] {f(\x)};
  \addplot[blue, smooth, domain=-1.85:1.85, line width=1, name path=curve_g] {g(\x)};

  \path[domain=-1.85:0, name path=f(x)_1] plot (\x, {f(\x)});
  \path[domain=-2:0, name path=g(x)_1] plot (\x, {g(\x)});
  \path[name intersections={of=f(x)_1 and g(x)_1, by=A}];
  \node[circle, fill=green, minimum size=6pt, inner sep=0pt] at (A) {};

  \draw[gray, dashed] (A) -- (A |- 0,0);

  \path[name path=base]
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

  \addplot[red] fill between [of=g(x)_1 and base, soft clip={(A) rectangle (-1,0)}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you want to use `intersections` as well to identify the left minimum of the blue curve:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    f(\x)=pow(\x,2)+2;
    g(\x)=pow(\x,4)-2*pow(\x,2)+1;
  }]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines*=middle, axis line style={-stealth'}, major tick length=2pt,
  every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=west}, 
  xlabel=$x$,
  every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=south}, 
  ylabel={$y$},
  enlargelimits=upper, % ticks=none,
  ymin=-0.5, xmin=-2.3,
  ]

  \addplot[red, smooth, domain=-2:2, line width=1, name path=curve_f] {f(\x)};
  \addplot[blue, smooth, domain=-1.85:1.85, line width=1, name path=curve_g] {g(\x)};

  \path[domain=-1.85:0, name path=f(x)_1] plot (\x, {f(\x)});
  \path[domain=-2:0, name path=g(x)_1] plot (\x, {g(\x)});

  \path[name intersections={of=f(x)_1 and g(x)_1, by=A}];
  \node[circle, fill=green, minimum size=6pt, inner sep=0pt] at (A) {};

  \draw[gray, dashed] (A) -- (A |- 0,0);

  \path[name path=base]
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

  \path[name intersections={of=base and g(x)_1, by=B}];
  \node[circle, fill=green, minimum size=6pt, inner sep=0pt] at (B) {};

  \addplot[red] fill between [of=g(x)_1 and base, soft clip={(A) rectangle (B)}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well done (+1). Perhaps You can comment or delete this line:
\draw[gray, dashed, name path=edge_a] (A) -- (A |- 0,0);

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Yes, maybe. I didn't know whether the OP wanted to keep it or not. So, I left it (but simplified the syntax a bit in order to avoid loading the `calc` library).

Comment: I have tryed to post one answer to this question, with the help of getting the xcoordinate of fist point of intersection. Without success!.

Comment: I now removed the `name path` part from the dashed line ... which is a remainder from another attempt of mine to solve this ... It is not needed anymore

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you so much, vielen Dank, 谢谢 !